# Getting the IP-Address of the machine from batch scrip using "VirtualBox Host-Only"

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox, ip-address

I want to catch the IP-Address of my machine using a batch file.

I am using the below code:

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do set IPAddress=%%a
echo IP-Adress is %IPAddress%
```

I have Virtual Box also installed in my system. So, an Ethernet adapter is also installed for the `VB`, with name `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network`.

Now, whenever I am pinging my machine using `ComputerName`, I am getting the response from the `VB Host-Only Network` adapter.

```
ping %ComputerName% -4

Pinging CTH-0098 [192.168.56.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.56.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

But my actual system IP-Address is `192.168.0.100`

How to catch this IP address?

Comment: Actually your pc has now at least 2 IPv4 addresses, see ipconfig /all.

Comment: yes. 1. VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter  2. Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one interface, `ping` is not helpful. The `netsh` command gives you far more flexibity:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netsh interface ipv4 show addresses name^="Local Area Connection" ^|find "IP"') do for %%b in (%%a) do set "ip=%%b"
echo Your IP is: %ip%
```

Change `Local Area Connection` to your actual interface name (look for the exact name with `netsh interface show interface`)

Comment: Thanks Stephan. But, I cannot use this as, I will be using the same batch file across several machines. So, I need the solution to be as generic as possible.

Comment: `netsh` comes with [Windows XP with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/netsh-exe). I surely hope you are not working with even older Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not mentioning my concern clearly. I cannot use netsh because: I will be using this batch file across several machines and for those machines the interface names might not be same.

Comment: ok I understand. But if you have several adapters, how to choose the right one then? `ping` obviously can't decide correctly. When I'm right, the address you're looking for is one of `netsh interface ipv4 show config | find "IP"`? Which one?

Comment: I want the one with name "Ethernet". However, I can use the batch file as long as there is no change in the network adapter or network adapter name And if there is any change in the N/W adapter name I need to update the batch file. Although the chance of changing adapter name is less, the chance of using the adapter to "Wi-Fi" is there. Is there any other alternative to this? (other than using netsh)

Comment: Another option might be `wmic` (try `wmic nic get /value'). But I have a `Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM` on one computer, and `Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection` on another, so relying on "name Ethernet" seems not to be a good option.